# How to handle expired data in ArangoDB/AQL

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection containing session data with a time to live flag. I want to use AQL to query the session data, but I need to make sure that only "live" session are returned. Is it possible to restrict a query based on the the time to live attribute.

Example entry is

```
  {
    user: "marc",
    sessionData: {},
    expires: 1403678241
  }
```

AQL:

```
FOR u IN users FILTER u.user == "marc" return u
```

should return the user only if expiry is not reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the DATE_NOW() function in AQL to retrieve the timestamp for
"now". To convert it into something readable, you could use
DATE_ISO8601(DATE_NOW()). This requires ArangoDB 2.1 or higher.

Please note that the above work with UTC / Zulu times, without
adjustment for DST or timezones.

You can than use DATE_NOW in your queries as follows

```
FOR u IN users FILTER u.user == "..." and u.expires >= DATE_NOW() return u
```